# Do formula if condition is met - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following:

[image: excel table]

I want to create a seperate table that tallys the 'size' of each animal type. Like this:
[image: excel table]

I can get the tally all all 'skinny' animals in row B with `=COUNTIF(B:B,"skinny")`, however I want it to get the tally of all 'foxes', then another for all 'pigs'. Something like:
`=IF(A='fox'(COUNTIF(C:C,"skinny"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try **Countifs** function: `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6,$A9,$B$2:$B$6,B$8)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much